# Alignment of icon on left justified text on narrow screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a `textarea` field at the bottom of which I want to display two helper texts. The left most helper text contains a little icon and is left-justified. The right helper text is right-justified.

All is well.

However, on smaller screen sizes, some problems arise.

The example code below shows what happens and this attachment shows what I want to have happen instead.

What happens is that the left helper text gets placed onto separate lines and the icon is positioned vertically center of that block instead of at the top of the block. The right helper text also gets placed onto separate lines but we want it to be right aligned.

What we want:
[image]

What actually happens:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  resize: none;
}

.helpers {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.helper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 20px;
}

#help2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea id="text" name="text" placeholder="Placeholder"rows="8" col="10"></textarea>
  <div class="helpers">
    <!-- Some SVG icon I grabbed from the Internet. In practice, this is a React component that returns an SVG -->
    <div class="helper-wrapper">
        <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/acid.svg" />
        <span id="help1">This is some helper text</span>
    </div>
   
    <span id="help2">More help text</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I've tried adding `text-align: center` to the `span#help2` element and `align-items: start` on the icon itself at a certain breakpoint but that doesn't seem to work. Ideally, I don't want to have to calculate at what breakpoint the line breaks happen. I just want the icon to be positioned properly when they *do* happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add   `align-items: flex-start;` to the `helper-wrapper`:

```css
body{
  width: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  resize: none;
}

.helpers {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.helper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
  width: 20px;
}

#help2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea id="text" name="text" placeholder="Placeholder"rows="8" col="10"></textarea>
  <div class="helpers">
    <!-- Some SVG icon I grabbed from the Internet. In practice, this is a React component that returns an SVG -->
    <div class="helper-wrapper">
        <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/acid.svg" />
        <span id="help1">This is some helper text</span>
    </div>
   
    <span id="help2">More help text</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```